# Estimating gas revert transaction using 0x Protocol V4

Tags: polygon, 0x

Whenever I try to `estimateGas` from a `ERC1155Order` I got a transaction revert, using Polygon Mumbai with Alchemy.

```
let sellOrder = new ERC1155Order({
    direction: TradeDirection.SellNFT,
    maker: alice.address,
    taker: bob.address,
    expiry: expirationTimeTS,
    nonce: 11,
    erc20Token: WETHAddress,
    erc20TokenAmount: 1, 
    fees: [],
    erc1155Token: ERC1155Address, 
    erc1155TokenId: "22897246053033895809978563905910150239444766161035846617439399460178038358017",
    erc1155TokenProperties: [],
    erc1155TokenAmount: 1,
    chainId: 80001,
});

const contractWrappers = new ContractWrappers(provider, {chainId: 80001});
let zeroEx = contractWrappers.exchangeProxy;
let txValidate = await zeroEx.getERC1155OrderHash(sellOrder).estimateGasAsync({ from: bob.address });
```

At alchemy I got this payload:

```
{
  "method": "eth_estimateGas",
  "params": [
    {
      "data": "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",
      "to": "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff",
      "from": "0x04ebdfca9c91d299dcb312d23e58ac0cdeef418e"
    }
  ],
  "id": 42,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

And the response:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 42,
  "error": {
    "code": 3,
    "message": "execution reverted",
    "data": "0x734e6e1c1de3a7ac00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The revert error you're receiving is a "NotImplementedError." I don't think ERC1155Orders has been or will ever be deployed to Polygon Mumbai. Ropsten is the preferred testnet for 0x contracts.